# how to send a single String to a RestAPI endpoint using CURL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, curl

I have a @RestController with an endpoint that receives a single String :

```
@RestController
public class ScriptController {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScriptController.class);

public ScriptController(Engine engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/run", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object run(@RequestBody String script){
    return engine.run(script);
}
}
```

when I send a request to this endpoint using CURL :

```
curl --request POST localhost:9999/run --data-binary "testObj.hi()"
```

I am not receiving the exact String (`"testObj.hi()"`) in the Controller, instead I receive the following one :

```
testObj.hi%28%29=
```

what is the problem?

when I change the method from `POST` to `GET` (in both sides) it works! but I want to use `POST` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the request body is URL encoded in HTTP requests, and since there is no content-type header, spring boot doesn't decode the encoded characters.

Specifying `Content-Type` header will solve the problem, something like this:

```
curl --request POST localhost:8080/run --data-binary "testObj.hi()" -H 'Content-Type: text/utf-8'
```

It works in case of GET requests because parameters are expected to be URL encoded in case of GET request and they are decoded by the spring.